# Check if varible is an list in queryset django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to check if my variables are in my querySet.

Varialbes coming from a form:

```
def magazine_new(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        post.mag_no = request.POST.get('mag_no')

        post.cn1 = request.POST.get('cn1')
        post.cn2 = request.POST.get('cn2')
        post.cn3 = request.POST.get('cn3')
        post.cn4 = request.POST.get('cn4')
```

Then, I want to check if these CNs exist in this mag_no
I tried this, but didn't work.

```
if Magazine.objects.filter(prodc_magt_no__in = [post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4] and mag_no=post.mag_no):
   form.save()
   return redirect('someview')

else:
   return HttpResponse('Dind't exist or match to this magazine no')

return render(request,'cnCreate.html',{'form':form})
```

I'm having the error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
or in order tests, this query didn't work.

My database table is:

```
 ID     WORK_YMD    LINE_NM  MODEL_CODE    MAG_NO             PRODC_MAGT_NO 
        118002  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4035
        118003  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4027
        118004  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4039
        118005  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4037
        118006  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4038
```

How to do this query to check if these Cns exists in prodc_magt_no field in database

The magazine must be the same: post.mag_no = mag_no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use "and" in your filter function.

```
if Magazine.objects.filter(prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4], mag_no=post.mag_no):
    ...do something...
```

Comment: Hello JeyBee, tks for your answer, now I'm having the error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)", do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Can give me an updated filter you're calling so I can see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [membership identities](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to detect if an item is in a list.

```
if post.mag_no in [post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4]:
    form.save()
   return redirect('someview')

else:
   return HttpResponse('Dind't exist or match to this magazine no')

return render(request,'cnCreate.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Burgess, tks for your answer, I'm having the follow erro: "too many values to unpack (expected 2)". I post my database table in order to help to understand better, do you know whats is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

This is bad syntax:

```
Magazine.objects.filter(prodc_magt_no__in = [post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4] and mag_no=post.mag_no)
```

Instead, it should be:

```
Magazine.objects.filter(prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4], mag_no=post.mag_no)
```

Comment: Hello vojtos, tks for your answer, now I'm having the error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)", do you know how to fix it?

Comment: And do you initialize data for form class?

Comment: form = Form(data=request.POST)